# how can i open the "save as" box in c# (.net core 3.1)

Tags: c#, .net-core-3.1

Ive been looking all over for a way to save a file by bringing up a "save as" box but i can only find classes that don't exist in .net core 3.1.

(I am happy to use an external library if needed btw)

Comment: Running on Windows?

Comment: Have you tried [SaveFileDialog Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)?

Comment: iI running windows, and the SaveFileDialog Class doesn't exist in .net core 3.1